# Will the Java JRE close connections if an applications crases?

Tags: connection, java

Will the Java JRE close database connections if an applications crashes or exits without closing its active connections? If not is it the responsibility of the database to time out these connections?

I understand that if Java crashes then the database will need to time out all open connections as there is nothing else to do the job.

**EDIT**
Additional thought. If a WAR deployed in Tomcat crashes, will the Tomcat server cleanup the open connections?

Comment: This has been a hot debate around the office but I am unsure where to find the information

Comment: Define 'crash'. To some people it seems to mean nothing more than a caught exception. A real crash is when the entire process forcibly exits. In that case *all* process resources are released by the operating system: memory, files, connections, semaphores, shared memory, ... Without knowing what you're talking about it is impossible to comment further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends.

If your JRE itself crashes, it might not be able to close all the connections. If just your application crashes, it might be able to close connections when it frees the resources. This seems to be the case most of the time, in my experience, as long as the JRE itself does not die.  The best defence is of course proper error handling and making sure you do not have more connections open than required.

From my experience, it's better to set up a data source in Tomcat, that way, even if your application crashes, it's not an issue with open resources. I'm a rather big fan of making my application server handle as much resource management as possible, that way I am protected a bit more from my sometimes adventurous code.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared a few things up for me. We have set a low database timeout on our development server so that connections will always get closed even if we have a full JRE crash, this seems to be working.

Comment: That's the safest option, a full JRE crash is rare, but it does happen from time to time. It pays to be defensive in this case, I like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Most times your application should close the connections in any proper errorhandlers. I prefer to set up the data source in Tomcat, like Ewald mentioned. There you can define a maximum of connections, and a timeout in your `context.xml`. When your application stacks too much connections it will release it.

Comment: Indeed, having the container, like Tomcat, handle of that, removes a bit of strain on us poor developers.